# Two few arguments passed to public function constructor PHP

Tags: php, lumen, lumen-5.3

**mailService.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Services;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class mailService extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    /**
     * The data instance.
     *
     * @param $data
     */

    public $data;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        $address = 'janeexampexample@example.com';
        $subject = 'This is a demo!';
        $name = 'Jane Doe';

        return $this->view('emails.test')
                    ->from($address, $name)
                    ->cc($address, $name)
                    ->bcc($address, $name)
                    ->replyTo($address, $name)
                    ->subject($subject)
                    ->with([ 'test_message' => $this->data['message'] ]);
    }
}
```

**clientService.php**

```php
use App\Http\Services\mailService as EmailService;
/**
* @param $clientId
* @param $comp_id
*
* @return \App\Http\Models\clients|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
*/
public function getClient($clientId, $comp_id)
{
    $data = ['message' => 'This is a test!'];

    Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new EmailService($data));

    return $this->clientsRepository->getClient($clientId, $comp_id);
}
```

When I pass the argument `$data` to a new instance of `EmailService` I get an error saying

> too few arguments passed to constructor function

but I don't understand why if I'm passing `$data` in the `clientService`, thank you for your help in advance.

I'm using the Lumen Framework `5.3` and PHP `7.2` and this code sample was taken from [Sendgrid docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/laravel/).

Comment: @JeremyHarris Sorry this line got cut my mistake use App\Http\Services\mailService as EmailService;

Comment: Ok, well the instantiation is still misspelled. See my answer.

Comment: How are you accessing the `to` method while it is not static nor while you are using a _Facade_?

Comment: You're using the same class (`EmailService`) twice, but based on the docs, it looks like a different class has the `to` method.  They example they show is `Mail::to('john@example.com')->send(new TestEmail($data));` where the `TestEmail` class seems to be what you have as `EmailService`.

Comment: @PatrickQ I've tried changing it to Mail but when I do it says Mail class not found

Comment: Well, have you _written_ that class? Or copied/downloaded it from SendGrid? (not sure if it's something they supply or you're expected to)

Comment: No, I have not written or downloaded it I have changed it to Mail and updated my composer dependencies now I am back to the first error with too few arguments for function construct

Comment: Have you run `php artisan make:mail mailService`?  Also, could you post (copy/paste) the full and exact error message you are getting? I imagine there is more than just "too few arguments for function construct"

Comment: Does the `Mail::to` also displays the same error?

Comment: @PatrickQ According to the docs all that does is create a new file called mailService and I done that manually but copied all of the code from the page

Comment: @RaedYakoubi No

Comment: If the problem has been solved then please submit the answer and approve it instead of editing the question as that won't be helpful to others looking for an answer to the same question.

Comment: @ConorDonohoe  The `make:mail` command is what creates the `app/Mail` files.  So if you haven't done that, it would explain why "I've tried changing it to Mail but when I do it says Mail class not found" is happening.  [See Here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#generating-mailables)